# why tooltip appears wrong in my chart JS?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a chart that I have developed using Chart JS and it works good. The problem here is that when I hover on a point, the x axes of that point appears wrong! So for example in the image below, I am hovering on that orange point which have '23000' x axes point. but it appears '18428.91'! it has right values only with the first purple line on the bottom. I think the problem with the tooltip option but I do understand what’s the problem

[image]

html

```
 <div class="card-body">
                                        <canvas id="lineChart_1"></canvas>
                                    </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    
(function($) {
    /* "use strict" */

    
    /* function draw() {
        
    } */

 var dzSparkLine = function(){
    let draw = Chart.controllers.line.__super__.draw; //draw shadow
    
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    
  
    var lineChart1 = function(){
        
        
        if(jQuery('#lineChart_1').length > 0 ){


        //basic line chart
            const lineChart_1 = document.getElementById("lineChart_1").getContext('2d');
            
            lineChart_1.height = 100;

            new Chart(lineChart_1, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    
                    datasets: [
                        
                            
   { label: '5390',
    data: [         {x: 10000 , y: 58.81 },
              
                {x: 11000 , y: 57.34 },
              
                {x: 12000 , y: 55.99 },
              
                {x: 13000 , y: 54.21 },
              
                {x: 14000 , y: 52.09 },
              
                {x: 15000 , y: 49.32 },
              
                {x: 16000 , y: 45.53 },
              
                {x: 17000 , y: 41.87 },
              
                {x: 18000 , y: 36.87 },
              
                {x: 18428.91 , y: 34.15 },
              
         ],

                            borderColor: '#FF00FF',
                            borderWidth: "2",
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',  
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#FF00FF'},    { label: '6160',
    data: [         {x: 12000 , y: 76.66 },
              
                {x: 13000 , y: 75.7 },
              
                {x: 14000 , y: 74.15 },
              
                {x: 15000 , y: 72.38 },
              
                {x: 16000 , y: 70.14 },
              
                {x: 17000 , y: 68.08 },
              
                {x: 18000 , y: 64.76 },
              
                {x: 19000 , y: 60.64 },
              
                {x: 20000 , y: 55.75 },
              
                {x: 21000 , y: 49.57 },
              
                {x: 22000 , y: 42.18 },
              
         ],

                            borderColor: '#4472C4',
                            borderWidth: "2",
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',  
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#4472C4'},    { label: '6930',
    data: [         {x: 14000 , y: 97.17 },
              
                {x: 15000 , y: 96.06 },
              
                {x: 16000 , y: 94.58 },
              
                {x: 17000 , y: 93.3 },
              
                {x: 18000 , y: 91.41 },
              
                {x: 19000 , y: 89.35 },
              
                {x: 20000 , y: 86.44 },
              
                {x: 21000 , y: 82.95 },
              
                {x: 22000 , y: 79.01 },
              
                {x: 23000 , y: 73.08 },
              
                {x: 24000 , y: 65.36 },
              
                {x: 25000 , y: 55.55 },
              
                {x: 25357.89 , y: 50.67 },
              
         ],

                            borderColor: '#ED7D31',
                            borderWidth: "2",
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',  
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#ED7D31'},    { label: '7700',
    data: [         {x: 16000 , y: 119.81 },
              
                {x: 17000 , y: 119.22 },
              
                {x: 18000 , y: 117.988 },
              
                {x: 19000 , y: 116.55 },
              
                {x: 20000 , y: 115.05 },
              
                {x: 21000 , y: 113.003 },
              
                {x: 22000 , y: 110.186 },
              
                {x: 23000 , y: 108.44 },
              
                {x: 24000 , y: 104.15 },
              
                {x: 25000 , y: 99.4 },
              
                {x: 26000 , y: 93.33 },
              
                {x: 27000 , y: 84.8 },
              
                {x: 28000 , y: 68.7 },
              
                {x: 28264.22 , y: 60.7 },
              
         ],

                            borderColor: '#A5A5A5',
                            borderWidth: "2",
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',  
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#A5A5A5'},    { label: '8085',
    data: [         {x: 19000 , y: 130.56 },
              
                {x: 20000 , y: 129.3 },
              
                {x: 21000 , y: 127.6 },
              
                {x: 22000 , y: 126.08 },
              
                {x: 23000 , y: 123.7 },
              
                {x: 24000 , y: 121.088 },
              
                {x: 25000 , y: 117.9 },
              
                {x: 26000 , y: 113.6 },
              
                {x: 27000 , y: 108.2 },
              
                {x: 28000 , y: 99.17 },
              
                {x: 29000 , y: 84.9 },
              
                {x: 29555.19 , y: 66.15 },
              
         ],

                            borderColor: '#0070C0',
                            borderWidth: "2",
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',  
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#0070C0'},  {
      label: 'Efficiency',
      data: [
       
        {x: 17000, y: 100}
      ],
      borderColor: 'black'
    } ],                   
                },
            options: {
      interaction: {
            mode: 'y'
        },scales: {
  x: {
    type: 'linear'
  }
}
    }
            });
            
        }
    }
    
    
   


    /* Function ============ */
        return {
            init:function(){
            },
            
            
            load:function(){
            
                lineChart1();   
           
            },
            
            resize:function(){
                
                lineChart1();   
            
            }
        }
    
    }();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    });
        
    jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
        dzSparkLine.load();
    });

    jQuery(window).on('resize',function(){
        dzSparkLine.resize();
        
    });     

})(jQuery);


</script>
```

After Editing:[image]

Comment: Cant seem to reproduce it, with interaction mode y it is bad but not like your screenshot so it seems it doesnt take it and without it just works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/6q4v3cek/3/

Comment: @LeeLenalee bro i still do not know what the heck is my problem!! ... I have removed the mode y and it still gives me the same result!!

Comment: Yeah but its not reproducable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line charts default to a [linear](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) Y axis and a [category](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html) X axis. Specifying `data.labels` explicitly sets labels for the x-axis category ticks but these are just text, and won't match the computed scale.

As `x` and `y` values are passed both axes need to be linear:

1. Remove the `data.labels` array.
2. Add the following to `options`:

   ```
   scales: {
     x: {
       type: 'linear'
     }
   }
   ```

---

Working example:

```js
(function($) {
  /* "use strict" */


  /* function draw() {
      
  } */

  var dzSparkLine = function() {
    //let draw = Chart.controllers.line.__super__.draw; //draw shadow

    var screenWidth = $(window).width();


    var lineChart1 = function() {


      if (jQuery('#lineChart_1').length > 0) {


        //basic line chart
        const lineChart_1 = document.getElementById("lineChart_1").getContext('2d');

        lineChart_1.height = 100;

        new Chart(lineChart_1, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
            /*labels: [10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 18428.91, 19000, 20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 25000, 25357.89, 26000, 27000, 28000, 28264.22, 29000, 29555.19],*/
            datasets: [{
              label: '5390',
              data: [{
                  x: 10000,
                  y: 58.81
                },

                {
                  x: 11000,
                  y: 57.34
                },

                {
                  x: 12000,
                  y: 55.99
                },

                {
                  x: 13000,
                  y: 54.21
                },

                {
                  x: 14000,
                  y: 52.09
                },

                {
                  x: 15000,
                  y: 49.32
                },

                {
                  x: 16000,
                  y: 45.53
                },

                {
                  x: 17000,
                  y: 41.87
                },

                {
                  x: 18000,
                  y: 36.87
                },

                {
                  x: 18428.91,
                  y: 34.15
                },

              ],

              borderColor: '#FF00FF',
              borderWidth: "2",
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pointBackgroundColor: '#FF00FF'
            }, {
              label: '6160',
              data: [{
                  x: 12000,
                  y: 76.66
                },

                {
                  x: 13000,
                  y: 75.7
                },

                {
                  x: 14000,
                  y: 74.15
                },

                {
                  x: 15000,
                  y: 72.38
                },

                {
                  x: 16000,
                  y: 70.14
                },

                {
                  x: 17000,
                  y: 68.08
                },

                {
                  x: 18000,
                  y: 64.76
                },

                {
                  x: 19000,
                  y: 60.64
                },

                {
                  x: 20000,
                  y: 55.75
                },

                {
                  x: 21000,
                  y: 49.57
                },

                {
                  x: 22000,
                  y: 42.18
                },

              ],

              borderColor: '#4472C4',
              borderWidth: "2",
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pointBackgroundColor: '#4472C4'
            }, {
              label: '6930',
              data: [{
                  x: 14000,
                  y: 97.17
                },

                {
                  x: 15000,
                  y: 96.06
                },

                {
                  x: 16000,
                  y: 94.58
                },

                {
                  x: 17000,
                  y: 93.3
                },

                {
                  x: 18000,
                  y: 91.41
                },

                {
                  x: 19000,
                  y: 89.35
                },

                {
                  x: 20000,
                  y: 86.44
                },

                {
                  x: 21000,
                  y: 82.95
                },

                {
                  x: 22000,
                  y: 79.01
                },

                {
                  x: 23000,
                  y: 73.08
                },

                {
                  x: 24000,
                  y: 65.36
                },

                {
                  x: 25000,
                  y: 55.55
                },

                {
                  x: 25357.89,
                  y: 50.67
                },

              ],

              borderColor: '#ED7D31',
              borderWidth: "2",
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pointBackgroundColor: '#ED7D31'
            }, {
              label: '7700',
              data: [{
                  x: 16000,
                  y: 119.81
                },

                {
                  x: 17000,
                  y: 119.22
                },

                {
                  x: 18000,
                  y: 117.988
                },

                {
                  x: 19000,
                  y: 116.55
                },

                {
                  x: 20000,
                  y: 115.05
                },

                {
                  x: 21000,
                  y: 113.003
                },

                {
                  x: 22000,
                  y: 110.186
                },

                {
                  x: 23000,
                  y: 108.44
                },

                {
                  x: 24000,
                  y: 104.15
                },

                {
                  x: 25000,
                  y: 99.4
                },

                {
                  x: 26000,
                  y: 93.33
                },

                {
                  x: 27000,
                  y: 84.8
                },

                {
                  x: 28000,
                  y: 68.7
                },

                {
                  x: 28264.22,
                  y: 60.7
                },

              ],

              borderColor: '#A5A5A5',
              borderWidth: "2",
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pointBackgroundColor: '#A5A5A5'
            }, {
              label: '8085',
              data: [{
                  x: 19000,
                  y: 130.56
                },

                {
                  x: 20000,
                  y: 129.3
                },

                {
                  x: 21000,
                  y: 127.6
                },

                {
                  x: 22000,
                  y: 126.08
                },

                {
                  x: 23000,
                  y: 123.7
                },

                {
                  x: 24000,
                  y: 121.088
                },

                {
                  x: 25000,
                  y: 117.9
                },

                {
                  x: 26000,
                  y: 113.6
                },

                {
                  x: 27000,
                  y: 108.2
                },

                {
                  x: 28000,
                  y: 99.17
                },

                {
                  x: 29000,
                  y: 84.9
                },

                {
                  x: 29555.19,
                  y: 66.15
                },

              ],

              borderColor: '#0070C0',
              borderWidth: "2",
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pointBackgroundColor: '#0070C0'
            }, {
              label: 'Efficiency',
              data: [

                {
                  x: 17000,
                  y: 100
                }
              ],
              borderColor: 'black'
            }],
          },
          options: {
            interaction: {
              //mode: 'y'
            },
            scales: {
              x: {
                type: 'linear'
              }
            }
          }
        });

      }
    }





    /* Function ============ */
    return {
      init: function() {},


      load: function() {

        lineChart1();

      },

      resize: function() {

        lineChart1();

      }
    }

  }();

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {});

  jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    dzSparkLine.load();
  });

  jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {
    dzSparkLine.resize();

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <canvas id="lineChart_1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: when I remove the data.labels array and I the option you wrote, it gives me this  , https://drive.google.com/file/d/17bTJ5U1JKf1FurEwjIZhPBOzVWg4YS7n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Hassan I won't be clicking a random google drive link. Please edit all relevant debugging information into your question.

Comment: I edited it now

Comment: @Hassan Thank you. I've added a working snippet to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much tim. now it worked but I would lie if I said that I knew whats the problem!